# jquery get content from an updating span

Tags: jquery

I have a form with pricing options that update depending on your selections made in the form.
The price itself updates in:

```
<span class="total-price"></span>
```

After submitions a div that has the initial state display:none; changes to block and display a thank you message.

I'm having trouble with pulling the content from that span and adding it to my thank you message where I also want to break down the costs.

I have something like this:

```
jQuery('.total-price').change(function(){
    var quotetotal = jQuery(this).html();
  var taxable = val( (quotetotal/ 100) * 20);
  jQuery('#tax').html(taxable);
  });
```

Comment: share your form please

Comment: Can I send you a message with the url to it?

Comment: yes u can do that

Comment: I have a dumb question but  does stackoverflow allows privat messages? if so I can't seem to find it.

Comment: why not post url in your question instead!

Comment: Don't just post a link to your website, instead provide a [mcve] snippet of your code in the question. Otherwise, when other people, in the future have a similar question your website will no longer show the problem since you will (or should have) corrected it.

Comment: Thanks you soo much for all your help. I've added the script in the ajax window and it works now :) I parsed the value via php to the ajax page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use $(this).text(); instead of .html()

Comment: Give me a moment to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Take the content from the span when the value in the select option is changed.

Try the below code :

```html
jQuery('select').change(function(){
  var quotetotal = jQuery('.total-price').html();
  var taxable = (quotetotal/ 100) * 20;
  jQuery('#tax').html(taxable);
});
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. The span id="tax" remains empty.

Comment: Oups my bad the success message is being pulled as ajax. That's why it's not updating the #tax field because it's a different file.